# Do you need to include additional sentinel tags when you are using VR2AR receivers for a VPS system?

Tags: r, telemetry, acoustics

I will be working on a ~12 reciver VPS system to look at the spawning behaviour of a cold lake fish and was wondering, if I am using all VR2AR 69kHz receivers for the project, which have built-in transmitters, will I have to put additional sentinel tags throughout my array to calculate the system/array performance? Or are the built-in transmitters enough for evaluating both detection efficiency throughout the time of the study AND system performance?

We plan on doing pre-deployment range testing to help inform the distance of the VPS receivers. But I am unsure how to go about doing sentinel range testing.

Any experience is helpful!

Comment: Hi - I think this is probably more suited to the electrical engineering stack, since stackoverflow is for specific questions about programming.

Comment: Is there a scientific stack?? I haven't found one yet!